# How can I update the Quantity field in DBGrid using SQL query in in Delphi (adotable)?

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I have field (quantity) in table1 (product) 
and I have a field (quantity_delivered) in table2 (Sale).
 Every time I sell a product, the quantity in table1 must be updated
 (quantity-quantity_delivered).

How can I do that in Delphi?
nedd idea 
help

Comment: Welcome! This sounds like a basic question, working with the ADO components, but unfortunately your question lacks every details about what you already have, what exactly you're stuck with, and so on.

Comment: google yourself a tutorial on Delphi's data-aware (aka db-aware) components; they are ideal for this sort of task  See e.g. http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Using+Data-Aware+Controls/

Answer (score -2):

Use a TAdoQuery component with a SQL statement like this:

```
ADOQuery.SQL.Text :=
'UPDATE product'
+ ' SET quantity = quantity - :quantity_delivered'
+ ' WHERE product_key = :product_key';

ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('quantity_delivered').DataType := ftInteger;
ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('quantity_delivered').Value := 42;

ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('product_key').DataType := ftInteger;
ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('product_key').Value := 123;

ADOQuery.ExecSQL;
```

This code is working with SQL parameters. This is helpful for preventing SQL injection hacks, because the parameter values are converted and escaped properly.

Since you did not provide much details of your table layouts, I had to make up more of an example how this has do be done!
Please check the data type of the primary key of table `product` or however you are identifing a single product and adjust the parameter properties `DataType` and `Value`, and also the identifier `"product_key"` in the SQL command!
You will also have to insert a variable for the `quantity_delivered` parameter value as you surely don't want to reduce the quantity by 42 everytime.

Comment: Seems like a red herring to me.  Why wouldn't the OP just use db-aware components to input/change the data?

Comment: I am a beginner in the Delphi
I have a hard time understanding what you said to me
It will give you the details you want
And try to guide me to the steps
And thank you very much

Comment: As a beginner, you don't need to understand the stuff in this answer to use Delphi productively for working with your data.  Look at tutorials like the one I mentioned in my comment on your q.

Comment: Yes, db-aware controls without needing nearly as much code as creating your own UPDATE sql statements.  But read a tutorial like the one I mentioned.